# Commenting functions with phpdoc adds "use" at the top of classes in laravel. Does it make the application slower?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, optimization, phpdoc

Writing comments for Laravel functions with phpdoc requires to add classes. For example

```
    /**
     * Add item to cart and redirect back
     *
     * @return Response
     */
```

Automatically adds "\Illuminate\Http\Response" to the top of class like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class CartController extends Controller{
```

My question is: does it make it (at least a tiny bit) slower if I'm not using the class in the code (only in the comment)? Another option would be to write "@return \Illuminate\Http\Response" which does not include the class and since it's just a comment it shouldn't have any performance hit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would one care about the performance of a comment? Don't you have something to do?

Comment: If the class is included in the "includes" section of the class file I wonder if the class is actually loaded. And if it is - does it affect performance.

Comment: `use` does not really affect performance in any measurable way. If you have `use A\B\C;` It's just tells the PHP interpreter "When you see `C` I mean `A\B\C`" which is an easy thing to keep track of using e.g. a map. `use` does not actually trigger autoloading

Comment: @apokryfos I had a feeling. Really useful to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it will not make a big difference. But if you're using PHP 7 or higher, you can mention return type in the code itself rather than in the comment. It'll help you, IDE, and the compiler to understand what to expect and your code will be protected from dynamic returns. So instead of doing,

```php
/*
 * @return Response
 */
public function index() {}
```

You can do,

```php
public function index() : Response {}
```

Comment: Most of this is true and good info, but has absolutely nothing to do with OP's question.  And the only sentence that has any relevance ("*Technically it will not make a big difference*") is wrong!  It makes *no* difference at all, as discussed in the comments on the question.

Comment: Nice to know that. Thank you for making it clearer.